What is the correct term for maximal/minimal "thickness" of convex hull in ℝ³?
Let me explain what I mean with thickness.
In this JSCAD example I use 3x3 linear transformation matrix G for ternary quadratic form Q from Dirichlet 1850 …

… to transform convex hull of points in ℤ³ with L2 norm 17 (blue, transparent) to another convex set. The vertices of that set are red, the edges of that convex hull faces are green.
Now for a given vector I take two tangential planes to that vector, so that the red/green convex hull touches both planes, and all the remaining of that convex hull is between both planes. The distance of the planes is what I call "thickness" for the given tangential vector not knowing the correct term. I am interested in minimal and maximal thickness among all tangential vectors.
Besides the correct term for "thickness", are there known (efficient) algorithms for determining minimal and/or maximal thickness?

I assume these planes are parallel? Also, are the green edges supposed to be lines or line segments? I assume that some of the red vertices are out of view? I don't think your illustration is particularly illustrative.

You may want to look into Urysohn widths.

"I assume these planes are parallel? "
—
Yes, because they are both tangential to same vector.

"You may want to look into Urysohn widths." — thanks, I am not sure that those widths help for the problem stated, but using "width" and "convex hull" for searches I found an interesting paper with definitions along what I described under "1.3 Preliminaries" (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.07028#page=3). The terms are width for what I called minimal thickness, and diameter for what I called maximal thickness. At least diameter can be easily (though not efficiently) determined as maximal distance between all pairs of convex set vertices.

@HermannSW "Tangential to a vector" is not really a term of art. It seems you mean "orthogonal to a vector", in which case, yes, the planes must be parallel. It could also refer to a tangent vector at a given point on the boundary, in which case, it's possible for there to be multiple such tangent planes. Saying a plane is tangential to a vector suggests, to me, that they are parallel, in the same way that a tangent is as close to "parallel" to a curve or surface as is possible. Anyway, it's clear enough now, given your answer.

For the minimal thickness, it is formally referred to as the "minimum zone flatness", you may want to look up the "minimum zone method" for an efficient algorithm to actually calculate the distance. BTW I did some research on this topic quite a while ago (2017).

For the maximal thickness, "diameter" seems to be a pretty descriptive term.

With the help of Mikhail I found document naming minimal/maximal "thickness" width/diameter in 1.3 Preliminaries.
I updated the JSCAD app for this thread to provide a "width/diameter" checkbox:

When selected, the red vertices of mapped convex hull and the determined diameter as white edge are shown. Browser console shows diameter length as "max:  735.1598465639972". That is done by comparing all pairs of vertices of the mapped set, so not efficient.
Remaining question is on whether there is an algorithm to determine convex set width?
(Section 1.3 in paper only defines it, and that paper is on random convex hulls)

@Vim provided hint to search for "minimum zone flatness".
There are many papers that are on determining convex hull/set width, some on different topics.
While searching around I stumbled over these related codes sofar:

Computational Geometry Algorithms Library
qhull.org
miniball  (for diameter)

P.S:
Miniball gist to determine convex set diameter using Miniball.hpp (matches length mentioned in previous answer):
$ ./miniball_int 
Center:
  0 0 0 
diameter:
  735.16
Number of support points:
  2
Relative error:
  0
Suboptimality:
  0
Validity:
  ok
Computation time was 1.1e-05 seconds
$


Wow, I carefully inspected CGAL packages:
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html
And found under "Optimal Distances":

… It further provides an algorithm to compute the width of a point set, …

https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polytope_distance_d/classCGAL_1_1Width__3.html

width determination demo

Since CGAL-4.12.1, you can no longer configure an in-source build in a
Git repository.

$ sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev
$ cd cgal/Polytope_distance_d/examples/Polytope_distance_d
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
$ make width_simplex
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/width_simplex.dir/width_simplex.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable width_simplex
[100%] Built target width_simplex
$ ./width_simplex 
Squared Width: 67108864/150994944
Direction: -4096 -8192 -8192 1
Planes: E1: -32768 -65536 -65536 0.  E2: -32768 -65536 -65536 65536
Number of optimal solutions: 1
$ 

JSCAD app link for the example.

Thanks for the comments and help leading to identifying the term "width" of a point set and above existing implementation in Computational Geometry Algorithms Library (CGAL).
P.S:
Simplest example with 8 pairs of (parallel) width-planes (67108864/50331648==4/3):
$ ./width_simplex 
Squared Width: 67108864/50331648
Direction: -4096 -4096 -4096 1
Planes: E1: -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768.  E2: -32768 -32768 -32768 32768
Number of optimal solutions: 8
$

JSCAD app link

P.P.S:
New cgal4gp repo makes point set width related CGAL functions available in PARI/GP:
cgal4gp repo
Works in different environments including termux under Android:

